# Python Traceback error on calling a method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm just toying around with python a bit and getting some errors (which seem to be the same) I don't understand.

So this is my sript:

```
import random
import os


def choose_number(bankAmount):

    print("Your bank amount:",bankAmount,"$")
    betAmount = float(input("Enter your bet amount: "))
    while (betAmount > bankAmount) | (betAmount <= 0):
        if betAmount > bankAmount:
            print("Your bet amount can't be higher then your bank amount!")
            betAmount = float(input("Please enter your bet amount again: "))
        else:
            print("Your bet amount can't be 0 or under.")
            betAmount = float(input("Please enter your bet amount again: "))
    bankAmount -= betAmount

    playerChance = str(input("Please choose your winchance from high, medium and low: "))
    while (playerChance != "high") & (playerChance != "medium") & (playerChance != "low"):
        print("You have to choose from 'high', 'medium or 'low'")
        playerChance = str(input("Please choose your winchance again: "))
    playerRoll = 0
    winAmount = 0.0
    if playerChance == "high":
        playerRoll = 60
        winAmount = betAmount * 1.5
    elif playerChance == "medium":
        playerRoll = 25
        winAmount = betAmount * 3.5
    else:
        playerRoll = 5
        winAmount = betAmount * 7.5

    roll_number(bankAmount, betAmount, playerRoll, winAmount)


def roll_number(bankAmount, betAmount, playerRoll, winAmount):

    random.seed
    rolledNumber = random.randint(1,100)

    if rolledNumber <= playerRoll:
        bankAmount += winAmount
        print("You won!\nWith a chance of",playerRoll,"% you won",winAmount,"$.\nThe rolled number were:",rolledNumber,".\nCongratulations!")
    else:
        print("You lost!\nThe rolled number were:",rolledNumber,".")

    play_again(bankAmount)


def play_again():

    playAgain = int(input("If you want to play again, enter 1: "))
    if playAgain == 1:
        choose_number(bankAmount)


def main():

    bankAmount = float(input("Enter your bank amount: "))
    while bankAmount <= 0:
        print("Your bank amount can't be under 0.")
        bankAmount = float(input("Please enter your bank amount again: "))

    choose_number(bankAmount)


main()
```

It works so far, but gives me still some errors:

```
Enter your bank amount: 500
Your bank amount: 500.0 $
Enter your bet amount: 50
Please choose your winchance from high, medium and low: high
You won!
With a chance of 60 % you won 75.0 $.
The rolled number were: 26 .
Congratulations!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/Projekte/moneyMultiplier.py", line 68, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/admin/Projekte/moneyMultiplier.py", line 65, in main
    choose_number(bankAmount)
  File "/Users/admin/Projekte/moneyMultiplier.py", line 34, in choose_number
    roll_number(bankAmount, betAmount, playerRoll, winAmount)
  File "/Users/admin/Projekte/moneyMultiplier.py", line 48, in roll_number
    play_again(bankAmount)
TypeError: play_again() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Since I'm kinda new to python and just wanted to play around a bit, I don't really have any idea how to fix this.

Any help would be loved.

Comment: You are calling `play_again(bankAmount)` (so with an argument) while `play_again` is defined as `def play_again():` (without an argument), so you have to define the function as: `def play_again(bankAmount):` or call it as `play_again()`

Comment: oh well.. didn't saw this.. thank you so much. I'm actually blind..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
play_again(bankAmount)
```

This here is the issue. Play again does not take any parameters. It actually asks for an input. Since you called this method with a parameter, it throws an error.

Also,

```
choose_number(bankAmount)
```

Since choose_number requires a parameter, and bank amount is not defined in the scope or play_again, calling main() instead of choose_number in play_again makes the app work.

Finally, as a part of learning a new language, you should make stack trace your best friend. While there are times where the error messages can be cryptic, in this case, it was very very clear. The last line of your traceback reads

```
TypeError: play_again() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```